# Visual Studio 2015 Keyboard Shortcut - Highlight function definition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Using some [visual studio keyboard shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/), **I'm trying to highlight a function definition in a more efficient way than *"Line Down Extend"* Shift+Down Arrow** (too many keystrokes).

The closest I can get is highlighting the body with ***"Goto Brace Extend"*
Ctrl+Shift+]**

[image]

However, this omits the function declaration `public Function()`. If the declaration is first highlighted with Shift+Down Arrow, it becomes un-highlighted when  Ctrl+Shift+] is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to select the current function definition:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (ts == null)
            return;
        EnvDTE.CodeFunction func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction] as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
        if (func == null)
            return;
        ts.MoveToPoint(func.GetStartPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartHeader));
        ts.MoveToPoint(func.GetEndPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well, and the plugin is very lean at 600KB, thanks. The visual-commander homepage is really helpful as well.