# is there any shortcut key for select the method body in visual studio(with or without resharper)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, shortcut

Sometimes I need to copy method body but recently I have to do this so often that's why I am searching a shortcut for this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192456/visual-studio-2015-keyboard-shortcut-highlight-function-definition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ReSharper's "[Extend Selection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Extend_Shrink_Selection.html)" to easily do this. Repeatedly hit the keyboard shortcut to extend the selection to the scope you want - `if` statement, `for` loop, method body, class declaration, etc. (There's an equivalent shortcut to shrink the selection, too, which will take you in the opposite direction.)

The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to extend selection and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to shrink selection.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio press Shift+Alt+]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.5.0

Press alt + shift + ¡ (exclamation mark) once for curret block or many times for successive deeper blocks.

Comment: I mean shallower, you know