# Visual Studio 2015 - Shortcut to select all method, function, sub

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

Do you know what is the shortcut key to select the entire Method,Function, Sub in Visual Studio 2015?

**For example:**
With the method below in Visual Basic, I would like to navigate to this method, press a shortcut to have the entire Sub selected.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192456/visual-studio-2015-keyboard-shortcut-highlight-function-definition

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround:

1. Navigate to the top of this Sub and press: **Ctrl + M + M**, the Sub will collapse into 1 line.
2. Select 3 rows including: (1)row above the Sub,  (2)the Sub, (3) row below the Sub
   and press: **Ctrl + K + C**

The entire Sub will be commented.