# Visual Studio 2017 - Is there a keyboard shortcut to copy the entire function under the cursor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a keyboard shortcut to copy the entire function under the cursor(without selection) in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: What do you mean _without selection_? If you don't want to select anything how do you think is it possible to _copy_ anything?

Comment: @Steve VS already has that, without selecting any text if you press Ctrl + C, it copies the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to copy the entire function under the cursor to the clipboard and assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (ts == null)
            return;
        EnvDTE.CodeFunction func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction] as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
        if (func == null)
            return;
        System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(func.GetStartPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartHeader).CreateEditPoint().GetText(func.GetEndPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes)));
    }
}
```

(It is similar to [Visual Studio 2015 Keyboard Shortcut - Highlight function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192456/visual-studio-2015-keyboard-shortcut-highlight-function-definition))